# Find ID's not present in a date represented by a yyyyweek_number

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've 2 data sets, one which represts a list of all of the customers and other with their order dates
The order date are in a yyyyweek_number format, so for instance as today (2020-09-29) is week 40, the order date would be represented as 202040

I want to get a list of dealers who haven't placed orders in 4 day ranges viz. 30 days or less
60 days or less
90 days or less and
90+ days

To illustrate lets say the customer dataset is as under:

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
+----+
```

and the Order table is as under:

```
+----+-----------------+
| ID | Order_YYYY_WEEK |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 |          202001 |
|  2 |          202003 |
|  3 |          202004 |
|  5 |          202006 |
|  2 |          202008 |
|  3 |          202010 |
|  6 |          202012 |
|  8 |          202009 |
|  1 |          202005 |
| 10 |          202015 |
| 11 |          202018 |
| 13 |          202038 |
| 15 |          202039 |
| 12 |          202040 |
+----+-----------------+
```

The slicer format that I've looks like this

[image]

Now say for instance the 30 days or less button is selected,
the resulting table should represent a table as under, with all the ID's from the Customer table that aren't present in the ORDER table where ORDER_YYYY_WEEK is 30 days from todays week

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 14 |
+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps:**

1. Create relationship between Customer id's in Customer table and Order table (if not already there)
2. Create a Date table
3. Convert Weeks to dates in a new calculated column in the Order table
4. Create relationship between Customer id's in Customer table and Order table
5. Create relationship between Dates in Date table and Order table
6. Create calculated column in Date Table with Day ranges ("30 days or less" etc)
7. Create measure to identify if an order was placed
8. Add slicer with date range from Date table and table visual with Customer id.
9. Add measure to table visual on filter pane and set to "No"

Some of these steps have additional detail below.

**2. Create a Date table**

We can do this is PowerQuery or in DAX. Here's the DAX version:

```
Calendar = 
VAR 
    Days = CALENDAR ( DATE ( 2020, 1, 1 ), DATE ( 2020, 12, 31 ) )
RETURN 

ADDCOLUMNS (
    Days,
    "Year Week", YEAR ( [Date] ) & WEEKNUM([Date])
)
```

Now mark this table as a date table in the "Table Tools" ribbon with the button "Mark as date table"

**3. Convert Weeks to dates**

For this to work, I have had to create a calculated column in the Order table with the first day of the year first. This can probably be improved upon.

```
StartYear = DATE(Left(Orders[Year week], 4), 01, 01)
```

Next the calculated column that we need in the Order table, that identifies the first day of the week. The Variable "DayNoInYear" takes the week number times 7 and substracting 7 to arrive at the first day of the week, returning the nth day of the year. This is then converted to a date with the variable "DateWeek":

```
Date = 
VAR DayNoInYear = RIGHT(Orders[Year week], 2) * 7 - 7
VAR DateWeek = DATEADD(Orders[StartYear].[Date], DayNoInYear, DAY)
RETURN
DateWeek
```

**6. Create calculated column in Date Table with Day ranges**

```
Day ranges = 
VAR Today = TODAY() 
VAR CheckDate = 'Calendar'[Date] RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    CheckDate - Today <= -90, "90+ days",
    CheckDate - Today <= -60 && CheckDate - Today > -90 , "90 days or less",
    CheckDate - Today <= -30 && CheckDate - Today > -60 , "60 days or less",
    CheckDate - Today <= 0 && CheckDate - Today > -30 , "30 days or less",
    "In the future"
)
```

**7. Create measure to identify if an order was placed**

```
Yes - No order = 
VAR Yes_No =
IF(
    ISBLANK(FIRSTNONBLANK(Orders[Customer id], Orders[Customer id])),
    "No", 
    "Yes"
)
VAR ThirtyDays = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Day ranges]) = "30 days or less"
VAR SixtyDays = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Day ranges]) = "30 days or less" || SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Day ranges]) = "60 days or less"
VAR NinetyDays = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Day ranges]) = "30 days or less" || SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Day ranges]) = "60 days or less" || SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Day ranges]) = "90 days or less"
RETURN

SWITCH(TRUE(),
    AND(ThirtyDays = TRUE(), Yes_No = "No"), "No",
    AND(SixtyDays = TRUE(), Yes_No = "No"), "No",
    AND(NinetyDays = TRUE(), Yes_No = "No"), "No",
    Yes_No = "No",
    "Yes"
)
```

**Steps 8 and 9**

Create slicer with the newly created "Day range" column in the Date table and create a table visual with the "Yes - No order" measure as visual-level filter set at "No" as in screenshot attached below

[image: Slicer and visual with filter]

Comment: Hi 

This almost works as intended but my main goal here is to show all the data until todays date, so for instance if 60 days or less is selected, then it should be showing data from less than 30 or less and 30 to 60 days, so on and so forth

Comment: Updated the "Yes - No order" measure. Please try if this does the trick.

Comment: Also updated text under section 8/9 and new screenshot (Filter set to "No")